# TypeError while returning Response from django view

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to create a view for the url pattern

Urls.py

`url(r'^task/', include('app.urls')),`

Urls.py inside `app.urls`

`url(r'^(?P<task_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.task, name='task'),`

Which can be accessed by `/task/:task_id`. My corresponding view for `task` is

```
def task(request, task_id):
    obj = Task.objects.get(pk=task_id)
    return HttpRequest("You're looking at a %s Task." % obj.type)
```

The corresponding model for Task is this.

```
class Task(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='tasks')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=7, default='en', choices=LANGUAGES)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Transliteration', choices=TASK_TYPES)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.language + ' ' + self.description
```

I am successfully able to debug the `task_id` and `obj` values which exist but my webpage returns the following error.

```
TypeError at /task/1/
__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

How can such an error be fixed?

Comment: Where is the __init__() for the task class? Or more precisely, if it's gettingf it from models.Model, then share that

Comment: I've been trying to follow the tutorial and there's no mention for the `__init__()` in the model. I've already shared the `class Task` above. Is there anything else that's needed?

Comment: I think you should return `HttpResponse` not `HttpRequest`

Comment: Thanks a million @latsha. That worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return `HttpResponse` instead of `HttpRequest`

```
def task(request, task_id):
    obj = Task.objects.get(pk=task_id)
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at a %s Task." % obj.type)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect.